# Error CS1061 “...Does Not Contain Definition and No Extension Method...accepting a first argument of type ” could be found

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to .NET visual studio, building windows Form Application.

I had the following error described below, when trying to build a solution. I am not sure if it has to do with something related to the file 'SuperAdventure.SuperAdventure' or a control that was not specified.

> 'SuperAdventure.SuperAdventure' **does not contain** a definition for '**label5_Click**' and **no extension method** 'label5_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'SuperAdventure.SuperAdventure' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

This is the error code with the error showing a red squiggly/line under the code in the marked line.

```
// lblExperience
// 
this.lblExperience.AutoSize = true;
this.lblExperience.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(110, 73);
this.lblExperience.Name = "lblExperience";
this.lblExperience.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(35, 13);
this.lblExperience.TabIndex = 6;
this.lblExperience.Text = "label7";
this.lblExperience.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.label5_Click); // <-- squiggly line here
```

and on the output it gives this:

1. 1>------ Build started: Project: Engine, Configuration: Release Any 
       CPU ------
2. 1>  Engine -> C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio
       2013\Projects\SuperAdventure\Engine\bin\Release\Engine.dll
3. 2>------ 
       Build started: Project: SuperAdventure, Configuration: Release Any
       CPU ------
4. 2>c:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio
       2013\Projects\SuperAdventure.Designer.cs(119,70,119,82): error
       CS1061: 'SuperAdventure.SuperAdventure' does not contain a
       definition    for 'label5_Click' and no extension method
       'label5_Click' accepting a    first argument of type
       'SuperAdventure.SuperAdventure' could be found    (are you missing a
       using directive or an assembly reference?)    ========== Build: 1
       succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Please let me know if I need to provided any more information. 
PS: I am a beginner trying to learn some C# by building a RPG game as an exercise.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow.  Can you provide the code you were using that caused this issue?  Looks like something is trying to reference `label5_Click` somewhere. In Visual Studio you can use `Ctrl+Shift+F` to find all references of a string in your solution.

Comment: It seems you accidently clicked on the label in the designer window and the designer added an event handler (`label5_Click`). Then you deleted that handler from your code file but forgot to delete this assignment in the designer.cs file.

Comment: This should be tagged WinForms not asp.net.  I started programming by wanting to write a game also, which caused me to buy a plethora of books and grind hard only to find out years later that I started out WAY over my head.  So don't shy from it but if you're open to some advice you have a long long long way to go.  I would go ahead and take the first leap into hours of videos and books that will save you alot of time and struggle before going much further.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick solution: Delete this.lblExperience and create it again.

The control can't seem to find its click event handler, and without getting too complex, deleting the control then double-clicking on it will create a fresh handler and correctly bind it.

Other quick solution: Delete that line. But then you have no handler for its click event, which may be intentional.

Comment: It was the equivalent of buying a new car because the old one was dirty, but glad it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

when you made the database with CodeFirst or use Identity for Register Users and you add your class to IdentityModes you can use from IDbSet and DbSet
if you over the IDbSet press the F12 you see that its does not access to async methods like FindAsync
but when you use from DbSet this method access to async methods and you can see it if you press F12 over the DbSet
when asp mvc make the controller and wives by it self and you use async mode you have some Errors by this text
Error CS1061 “…Does Not Contain Definition and No Extension Method…accepting a first argument of type ” could be found

you must go to the DbContext class and change IDbSet<> to DbSect<> and this error went and your project successfully run
thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

For me, I opened `IdentityModel` class and I modified the `System.Data.Entity`, 
the final result:

```
public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<EventSystem.Models.Admin> Admins { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I installed SpecFlow package to my .NET project . Uninstalling it fixed the issue